# django-photologue thumbnails not loading

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am trying to use django-photologue, I installed it and did mentioned settings.

I have a model Blog as follows:

```
class Blog(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    thumbnail = models.ForeignKey(Photo, related_name='blogs')
```

I am able to add images to blog objects, however I do not see the thumbnail in my admin interface (clicking on it basically opens base.html stored in templates folder which I simply copied from example_project, this base.html is not important for me, however seeing this thumbnail could be interesting):

NOTE: I guess my MEDIA_ROOT and MDIA_URL properties are wrong, I am not sure what I should be writing there. I get

```
GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/photologue/photologue/photos/cache/dog_1_admin_thumbnail.jpg 404 (Not Found)
```

for

```
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'photologue', )
MEDIA_URL = '/photologue/'
```

error, on my console.

[image]

My folder structure:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The thumbnails part of the question is fixed by doing following settings:

In my urls.py file I had to

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
    #all urls 
]+ static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

And in my settings.py file I added:

```
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'public', 'static')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'public', 'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```